# How to convert from .pb to .tflite?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have created a object detection model using `Pytorch` and then converted from `.pth` to `.onnx` and then `.pb`, but now I need to convert it into `.tflite` for android app! How to do it? It's my first time.

```
input_arrays  = [64, 3, 224, 224] 

output_arrays = ?
```

for binary classification.

I have done it from pytorch but everything I find to look at was from keras or Tensorflow...

This is the code I have used to convert it from `.pb` to `.tflie`

```py
converter = lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
  model/model.pb , input_arrays, output arrays )
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

```py
!tflite_convert \
   --output_file= model/model.tflite \
   --graph_def_file= model/model.pb \
   --input_arrays= input_arrays \
   -- output_arrays= output_arrays
```

I think it has something to do with input arrays and output arrays, but not sure about it. Is `graph_def_file` supposed to store `model.pb` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to specify input and output array, when using the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Try this out.

Comment: error:  "MetaGraphDef associated with tags {'serve'} could not be found in SavedModel. To inspect available tag-sets in the SavedModel, please use the SavedModel CLI: `saved_model_cli`
available_tags: []

Comment: I would advise you to train the model with tensorflow and then convert it to tflite. Because a lot of thing may be missed out in conversion from .pth to .onnx and then .pb. Generally, when we train in tensorflow a model.ckpt.meta file is generated, I guess it is looking for that file.

Comment: nah.. That doesnt solve as different problems and no explanation of problem. Any other way or things to try ?