# How to decrease size of .tflite which I converted from keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I just converted a `Keras model .h5(resnet50 img classify)` created on google `COLAB` to `.tflite` but the size just decreased like `0.5 MB`.

This is for a mobile application and size should decrease more. Its like 90MB and way too big for production.

OS Platform and Distribution = Linux-4.14.79+-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic

TensorFlow version = '1.14.0-rc1'

CUDA/cuDNN version = V10.0.130

GPU model and memory = 11441MB | Tesla K80

```
from tensorflow import lite
converter = lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file( '/gdrive/My Drive/Places/model.h5')
tfmodel = converter.convert()
open ("model.tflite" , "wb") .write(tfmodel)
```

I expect the size to decrease as firebase supports till 40MB? Where I am getting wrong or what should I do? I even used pytorch and converted till .pb from .pth but couldn't do

[How to convert from .pb to .tflite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56609185/how-to-convert-from-pb-to-tflite/56609367?noredirect=1#comment99795464_56609367)

Comment: Maybe you can set `converter.post_training_quantize=True` for a reduced size.

Comment: Some of the operators in the model are not supported by the standard TensorFlow Lite runtime. If those are native TensorFlow operators, you might be able to use the extended runtime by passing --enable_select_tf_ops, or by setting target_ops=TFLITE_BUILTINS,SELECT_TF_OPS when calling tf.lite.TFLiteConverter(). Otherwise, if you have a custom implementation for them you can disable this error with --allow_custom_ops, or by setting allow_custom_ops=True when calling tf.lite.TFLiteConverter(). Here is a list of operators for which you will need custom implementations: FusedBatchNormV3.

Comment: @Prabesh did you succeed in decreasing the size of your model? Please take a look at my own question, a bit different than yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57631313/i-use-tfliteconvert-post-training-quantize-true-but-my-model-is-still-too-big-fo :).  Thank you!