# I use TFLiteConvert post_training_quantize=True but my model is still too big for being hosted in Firebase ML Kit's Custom servers

Tags: python, firebase, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I have written a TensorFlow / Keras Super-Resolution GAN. I've converted the resulting trained `.h5` model to a `.tflite` model, using the below code, executed in Google Colab:

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/My Drive/srgan/output/srgan.h5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.post_training_quantize=True
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("/content/drive/My Drive/srgan/output/converted_model_quantized.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

As you can see I use `converter.post_training_quantize=True` which was censed to help to output a lighter `.tflite` model than the size of my original `.h5` model, which is 159MB. The resulting `.tflite` model is still 159MB however.

It's so big that I can't upload it to Google Firebase Machine Learning Kit's servers in the Google Firebase Console.

How could I either:

- decrease the size of the current `.tflite` model which is 159MB (for example using a tool),
- or after having deleted the current `.tflite` model which is 159MB, convert the `.h5` model to a lighter `.tflite` model (for example using a tool)?

## Related questions

[How to decrease size of .tflite which I converted from keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56620391/how-to-decrease-size-of-tflite-which-i-converted-from-keras): no answer, but a comment telling to use `converter.post_training_quantize=True`. However, as I explained it, this solution doesn't seem to work in my case.

Comment: Maybe you can decrease some layers from the generator or discriminator networks to have a *lighter* version of your model.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal by decreasing the number of residual blocks for example? I'll read some papers again to know if the generator should be deeper than the discriminator, or *vice-versa*, or if it doesn't matter

Comment: Reducing or increasing the number of residual blocks layers in the generator / discriminator wasn't sufficient. Is there any tool to decrease the size of the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, quantization means, shifting from dtype float32 to uint8. So theoretically our model should reduce by the size of 4. This will be clearly visible in files of greater size.

Check whether your model has been quantized or not by using the tool "https://lutzroeder.github.io/netron/". Here you have to load the model and check the random layers having weight.[The quantized graph contains the weights value in  uint8 format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMPkh.png)
[In unquantized graph the weights value will be in float32 format.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6oX6.png)

Only setting "converter.post_training_quantize=True" is not enough to quantize your model. The other settings include: 
converter.inference_type=tf.uint8
converter.default_ranges_stats=[min_value,max_value]
converter.quantized_input_stats={"name_of_the_input_layer_for_your_model":[mean,std]}

Hoping you are dealing with images.
 
min_value=0, max_value=255, mean=128(subjective) and std=128(subjective).
 name_of_the_input_layer_for_your_model= first name of the graph when you load your model in the above mentioned link or you can get the name of the input layer through the code "model.input" will give the output "tf.Tensor '**input_1**:0' shape=(?, 224, 224, 3) dtype=float32". Here the input_1 is the name of the input layer(NOTE: model must include the graph configuration and the weight.)

Comment: Applicable for tf  version 1.13 and above. Not sure about the below versions.

Comment: Mmmmh input and output layers are still `float32` not `uint8`, is it normal?

Comment: Nope. Input should be uint8. Output could be anything depends on the requirement.

Comment: @arvindkumarsoundarrajan: I have quantized my custom tflite object detection model. Before quantization the model size was ~53.4 MB and after quantization model size is 13.3 MB. But both models take nearly the same amount of time to perform inference. Could you please guide me?